# NetBeans Platform - 6.8 app no longer works in 6.9

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

All,

I have a netbeans platform app developed in 6.8 platform.  I'm trying to load it using NetBeans 6.9 and the build fails with the error

> Module org.netbeans.libs.jna excluded from the target platform

I have seen [someone write](http://netbeans.org/projects/usersguide/lists/nbdocs_feedback/archive/2010-08/message/152) that this error is related to the GUI builder being set to use automatic mode (swing layout extensions, deprecated library).  I have switched the GUI builder over to Swing 6 widgets, and have rewritten some of the UI code that was created through the GUI builder, so as to remove the dependency on the deprecated library.  I still get the error, though, even after having cleaned and rebuilt.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You may still have that library listed as a dependency under Libraries.  Look under the project and remove that as a dependency and try rebuilding.

Even if you are not using it, if it is listed as a dependency Netbeans will throw a build failure error if it cannot find it.

Comment: That project is not listing it as a dependency but I'm going through the dependent projects and seeing if they have it.  What a pain in the ass, I knew there was a reason I hate using GUI editors.  If people had used MigLayout none of this would have happened. .

Comment: Netbeans will list all the dependencies for a project under Libraries, including those from dependent projects.  If you don't see it there, it is probably something else.  Also, if you right click on the project and select Show Dependency Graph, you can see all the dependencies and how they relate which can help you find where things are coming from.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help.  I ended up giving up and going back to 6.8 where everything worked fine.